# Orchard data entry forms without admin

Tags: asp.net-mvc, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.8, orchard-modules

We're working diligently at learning Orchard, with a goal of creating not websites, but business-centric web applications that we would normally write in months using MVC, but hope to be much more efficient by using the various Parts already available.

The last mile, though, seems to be a big block -- how to tell Orchard that it should create a shape that allows the end-user to edit some data? There's a good bit on most of end-user editing at [Creating a module for Orchard that stores data from the front-end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18110063/creating-a-module-for-orchard-that-stores-data-from-the-front-end?rq=1) but it picks up after the data's already been entered and carries it through the controller's POST operation. What I can't figure out is how to get through the initial GET operation.

To elaborate, in straight MVC I might allow the user to enter information about themselves. So I'd have /Controllers/PersonController.cs and there write a Create() function. I'd add a View in /Views/Person/Create.cshtml and simply "return View()" from the controller. In Create(Person p), an HTTPGet method, I'd do the heavy lifting to save the object.

Now in Orchard I have my PersonPart and its PersonPartDriver which, as I understand from the above article, I would write my POST method to accept the PersonPart and save the object.

```
class PersonController : Controller
{
   private readonly IRepository<PersonPartRecord> personRepository;

   public PersonController(IRepository<PersonPartRecord> _personRepository) {
      personRepository = _personRepository;
   }

   [HttpPost]
   public Create(PersonPart part) {
      personRepository.Create(part.Record);
   }
}
```

All well, but how would I get Orchard to invoke the GET Editor(PersonPart, dynamic) method to get the form up for the user to do the initial data entry?

```
protected override DriverResult Editor(PersonPart part, dynamic shapeHelper)
{
    return ContentShape("Parts_Person_Edit",
                        () => shapeHelper.EditorTemplate(
                                          TemplateName: "Parts/Person",
                                          Model: part,
                                          Prefix: Prefix));
}
```

Or do I write the GET Create() method in the controller? If I do that, though, I'm bypassing the entire shape creation system, no? Something itches in the back of my brain saying I should rather be doing a Display() and, in the template, just making it an editable form, but I have a Display() for the readonly view of Person ... how to make it know I want the editable view?

Hope the question makes sense, and hope that someone can assist.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look to `Orchard.CustomForms`

```
var model = _contentManager.BuildEditor(contentItem);
 return View(model);
```

but you'll need something like the code above. You could return `ShapeResult(this,model)` too